# Tengo un problema al querer reutilizar un programa js

Tags: javascript, html, script, function

Hola soy nuevo en esto y tengo esta página que cifra o descifra un texto y lo muestra en un recuadro, el problema es que para cifrar/descifrar texto otra vez, tengo que recargar la página ya que si se vuelve a usar ya no pasa nada y eso es molesto, ya intente algunas ideas y no logro resolverlo, si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agradecería bastante

```js
function encriptado(){
    event.preventDefault();
    const textoNoEncriptado=document.querySelector(".text-area").value.toLowerCase();
    var txtCifrado = textoNoEncriptado.replace(/e/igm,"enter");
    var txtCifrado = txtCifrado.replace(/i/igm,"imes"); 
    var txtCifrado = txtCifrado.replace(/a/igm,"ai"); 
    var txtCifrado = txtCifrado.replace(/o/igm,"ober"); 
    var txtCifrado = txtCifrado.replace(/u/igm,"ufat");
    
    if(textoNoEncriptado!=""){
        const cuadroTxt=document.querySelector(".container-empty");
        cuadroTxt.className="result-container";
        while(cuadroTxt.firstChild) {
            cuadroTxt.removeChild(cuadroTxt.firstChild);
        }
        cuadroTxt.innerHTML= '<p class="result-text">'+txtCifrado+'</p>'+'\n';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
        <img src="resources/logo.png" class="logo">
        <form>
            <div class="text-container"><textarea placeholder="ingrese el texto aqui" class="text-area" maxlength="200"></textarea></div>
            <p class="aviso"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i>Sin acentos (máx 200 caracteres)</p>
                <button class="encriptar botones" onclick="encriptado()">Encriptar</button>
        </form>
        

        <div class="container-empty">
            <div class="dibujo"><img src="resources/dibujo.png" class="dibujo"></div>
            <p class="no-found"><b>Ningún mensaje fue encontrado</b></p>
            <p class="description">Ingresa el texto que deseas encriptar o descencriptar</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Ya intente de algunas formas intentar actualizar la variable cuadroTxt pero igualmente no logro resolver lo que eh dicho, todo funciona excepto ese detalle

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en esta 2 lineas:

```
const cuadroTxt=document.querySelector(".container-empty");
cuadroTxt.className="result-container";
```

A cuadroText le reemplazas la clase `container-empty` por `result-container` por lo que al volver a presionar el botón el selector no encuentra `container-empty` porque ya no existe.

Hay mil soluciones para esto, lo más simple es poner otra clase o un id al elemento html, yo ocuparé la última opción (id="Result") en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
function encriptado(){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    //cada vez que presionas el botón reestableces la clase a su valor default que en tu caso es container-empty
    const cuadroTxt=document.querySelector("#Result");
    cuadroTxt.className="result-container";
    
    
    const textoNoEncriptado=document.querySelector(".text-area").value.toLowerCase();
    var txtCifrado = textoNoEncriptado.replace(/e/igm,"enter");
    var txtCifrado = txtCifrado.replace(/i/igm,"imes"); 
    var txtCifrado = txtCifrado.replace(/a/igm,"ai"); 
    var txtCifrado = txtCifrado.replace(/o/igm,"ober"); 
    var txtCifrado = txtCifrado.replace(/u/igm,"ufat");
    
    if(textoNoEncriptado!=""){
        cuadroTxt.className="result-container";
        while(cuadroTxt.firstChild) {
            cuadroTxt.removeChild(cuadroTxt.firstChild);
        }
        cuadroTxt.innerHTML= '<p class="result-text">'+txtCifrado+'</p>'+'\n';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
   <form>
      <div class="text-container">
         <textarea placeholder="ingrese el texto aqui" class="text-area" maxlength="200"></textarea>
      </div>
      <p class="aviso"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i>Sin acentos (máx 200 caracteres)</p>
       <button class="encriptar botones" onclick="encriptado()">Encriptar</button>
   </form>
        
   <div id="Result" class="container-empty">
       <div class="dibujo"><img src="resources/dibujo.png" class="dibujo"></div>
       <p class="no-found"><b>Ningún mensaje fue encontrado</b></p>
       <p class="description">Ingresa el texto que deseas encriptar o descencriptar</p>
    </div>
</div>
```